# Is it possible to extract data such as `gasPrice`, `gasLimit`, `nonce`, etc. from the transaction that has been signed and serialized?

Tags: web3js, transactions

Is it possible to extract data such as `gasPrice`, `gasLimit`, `nonce`, etc. from the transaction that has been signed and serialized?

For example I use this code for sign tx:

```js
//Signing transaction
const txParams = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(suggestion_gas),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(estimate_gas),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(suggestion_gas),
    maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(suggestion_gas),
    to: token_address,
    value: '0x00',
    data: data,
    chainId: web3.utils.toHex(chainId),
}
const common = Common.custom({ chainId: chainId }, { hardfork: Hardfork.London });
const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData(txParams, { common });
const privateKey = Buffer.from(account.secret, 'hex');
const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey);
const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();
const serializedTxHex = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');

//Send signed transaction to blockchain.
await send_signed_transaction(serializedTxHex);
```

You can see `serializedTxHex` sent to another function for submit in the blockchain. Now I need details of transaction in the `send_signed_transaction` function. That if I can not access this, I have to send `txParams` to this function as well.